# Windows Server 2008 iis 7.5 classic asp mdb DB via DSN odbc

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, odbc, asp-classic

I had a a simple site on a 2003 IIS 6 server for years.
I have a small DB in a Mdb file.
Everything was great, until I've upgraded to a windows 2008 R2 64bit IIS 7.5 server.
I've transferred the site perfectly including adding ODBC (32bit), enabling 32bit in the applicationpool, everything.

The site is working just fine if I surf from within the server.

But when I connect to the server using VPN SSTP I can only pass the first Mdb file (very basic authentication-opens Mdb and checks whether the user and password are valid), but it won't show me my DB page. The browser alerts me with a TIME OUT error.

I gave almost the entire server EVERYONE Permissions with no success.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the title begins with `Please help meeeeeeeeee`.

Comment: "I've transferred the site perfectly" - If you did, it would work perfectly. How did you transfer it? What's in your main DB page code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that you firewall is not blocking any traffic. The firewalls between 2003 and 2008 R2 are radically different. I would try disabling the firewall, and those results will help you narrow it down.

You might also check that the IIS server has rights to the mdb file, and is using the correct permissions, and that something that was specific to the old server is still in a config file somewhere.